# Toy Forth interpreter

Tags: haskell, forth

I've been reading too many papers and writing too little code. These are my first 300 lines of Haskell:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction, TemplateHaskell #-}

module Forth where

import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as Map

import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Error

import Text.Read (readMaybe)

import Text.Parsec
import Control.Applicative hiding ((<|>), optional, many)

import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.Operators

import Safe


data Forth = Forth {
                    _stack :: [Integer],
                    _loopStack :: [Integer],
                    _heap :: Map.Map String [Exp]} deriving (Show)

data Exp = Cmt String | Dump | Num Integer | Plus | Min | Mul | Div | Mod | Dup | Swap | Drop | PP 
            | LoopIndex Int | In | Out String | CR | Eq | Lt | Gt
            | Word String [Exp] | Call String | If [Exp] [Exp] | DoLoop [Exp] Bool | Leave
    deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''Forth

type ForthS a = ErrorT String (StateT Forth IO) a

emptyForth :: Forth
emptyForth = Forth [] [] Map.empty

pushStack :: Integer -> ForthS ()
pushStack n = stack %= (n:)

popStack :: ForthS Integer
popStack = do
            s <- use stack
            case s of
                [] -> throwError "Empty stack. Can't pop!"
                (n:ns) -> do
                            stack .= ns
                            return n

dumpStack :: ForthS [Integer]
dumpStack = zoom stack get
--

pushLoopStack :: Integer -> ForthS ()
pushLoopStack n = loopStack %= (n:) 

popLoopStack :: ForthS Integer
popLoopStack = do
            s <- use loopStack
            case s of
                [] -> throwError "Empty loop stack. Can't pop!"
                (n:ns) -> do
                            loopStack .= ns
                            return n

--(.?) :: MonadState s m => Getting s1 s s1 -> Getting (f a) s1 a -> m (Maybe a)
(.?) a b = do
    v <- use a
    return (v ^? b)

peekLoopStack :: Int -> ForthS Integer
peekLoopStack i = do
            --a <- (loopStack .? ix i)
            a <- zoom loopStack (gets $ flip atMay i)
            case a of 
                Just n -> return n
                Nothing -> throwError $ "Loop stack is empty."

--
setWord :: String -> [Exp] -> ForthS ()
setWord word val = heap %= (Map.insert word val)

getWord :: String -> ForthS [Exp]
getWord word = do
                h <- use heap
                case Map.lookup word h of
                    Just a -> return a
                    Nothing -> throwError $ "Word \"" ++ word ++ "\" is not defined."

-----------------------



execProg :: [Exp] -> IO ()
execProg xs = do
    (success, machine) <- runProg xs
    case success of
        Left m  -> putStrLn $ "\nFailed: " ++ m ++ show machine
        Right _ -> putStrLn $ "\nOk: " ++ show machine

runProg :: [Exp] -> IO (Either String (), Forth)
runProg xs = runEval (mapM_ eval xs)

runEval :: Eval -> IO (Either String (), Forth)
runEval ev = runStateT (runErrorT ev) emptyForth


type Eval = ForthS ()

eval :: Exp -> Eval
eval (Cmt _) = return ()
eval (Dump) = do
    ns <- dumpStack
    liftIO $ print ns
eval (Num n) = pushStack n
eval (Plus) = do
    a <- popStack
    b <- popStack
    pushStack (b+a)
eval (Min) = do
    a <- popStack
    b <- popStack
    pushStack (b-a)
eval (Mul) = do
    a <- popStack
    b <- popStack
    pushStack (b*a)
eval (Div) = do
    a <- popStack
    b <- popStack
    pushStack (b `div` a)
eval (Mod) = do
    a <- popStack
    b <- popStack
    pushStack (b `mod` a)
eval (Dup) = do
    a <- popStack
    pushStack a
    pushStack a
eval (Swap) = do
    a <- popStack
    b <- popStack
    pushStack a
    pushStack b
eval (Drop) = do
    _ <- popStack
    return ()
eval (PP) = do
    a <- popStack
    liftIO $ print a
eval (LoopIndex i) = do
    n <- peekLoopStack i
    pushStack n
eval (In) = do
    s <- liftIO getLine
    case readMaybe s of
        Just n -> pushStack n
        Nothing -> throwError $ "Input \"" ++ s ++ "\" is not a number."
eval (Out s) = liftIO $ putStr s
eval (CR) = liftIO $ putStrLn ""
eval (Eq) = do
    a <- popStack
    b <- popStack
    pushStack (if b==a then 1 else 0)
eval (Lt) = do
    a <- popStack
    b <- popStack
    pushStack (if b<a then 1 else 0)
eval (Gt) = do
    a <- popStack
    b <- popStack
    pushStack (if b>a then 1 else 0)
eval (Word key val) = setWord key val
eval (Call key) = do
    val <- getWord key
    mapM_ eval val
eval (If yes no) = do
    a <- popStack
    mapM_ eval (if a/=0 then yes else no)
eval (Leave) = mzero
eval (DoLoop xs plusLoop) = do
    idx <- popStack
    lim <- popStack
    pushLoopStack lim
    pushLoopStack idx
    let go lim idx = do
        mapM_ eval xs
        inc <- if plusLoop then popStack else return 1
        guard $ not $ if inc >= 0 then (lim < idx) `xor` (lim <= idx + inc) else (lim <= idx) `xor` (lim < idx + inc)
        _ <- popLoopStack
        _ <- popLoopStack
        pushLoopStack lim
        pushLoopStack (idx + inc)
        go lim (idx + inc)
    let finish = do
        _ <- popLoopStack
        _ <- popLoopStack
        return ()
    mplus (go lim idx) finish


xor :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
x `xor` y = (x || y) && not (x && y)

-----------------------------

execParse :: String -> IO ()
execParse = execProg . parseForth

parseForth :: String -> [Exp]
parseForth s = case parse forthParser "YOLO" s of
    Left e -> [Out $ "ERROR PARSED: " ++ show e]
    Right xs -> xs



forthParser = ws *> many forthExp <* eof


forthExp = foldl1 (<||>) $ map (\e-> e <* (ws1 <|> eof))[
    comments >>= pure . Cmt,
    integer >>= pure . Num, -- negative numbers suck
    char '-' *> pure Min,
    char '+' *> pure Plus,
    char '*' *> pure Mul,
    char '/' *> pure Div,
    char '.' *> pure PP,
    char '=' *> pure Eq,
    char '<' *> pure Lt,
    char '>' *> pure Gt,
    char '%' *> pure Mod, 
    char 'i' *> pure (LoopIndex 0),
    char 'j' *> pure (LoopIndex 2),
    char 'k' *> pure (LoopIndex 4),
    string "false" *> pure (Num 0),
    string "true" *> pure (Num 1),
    string "CR" *> pure CR,
    string "dump" *> pure Dump,
    string "dup" *> pure Dup,
    string "swap" *> pure Swap,
    string "drop" *> pure Drop,
    string "in" *> pure In,
    string "leave" *> pure Leave,
    ifThenElse,
    doLoop,
    stringLike >>= pure . Out ,
    definition,
    many1 alphaNum >>= pure . Call -- if it isn't a keyword, it must be a call
    ]


p <||> q = try p <|> q

ws = skipMany (oneOf " \n\r")
ws1 = skipMany1 (oneOf " \n\r")
lexeme p = ws *> p <* ws

integer = rd <$> (plus <|> minus <|> number)
    where rd     = read :: String -> Integer
          plus   = char '+' *> number
          minus  = (:) <$> char '-' <*> number
          number = many1 digit

stringLike = char '\'' *> many (noneOf ['\'']) <* char '\''

comments = char '(' *>  many (noneOf [')' , '\r', '\n']) <* char ')'

definition = do
    char ':'
    name <- lexeme (many1 alphaNum)
    prog <- forthParser
    char ';'
    return $ Word name prog

ifThenElse = do
    string "if"
    ws
    yes <- manyTill forthExp (try $ lookAhead $ string "else" <|> string "then")
    no <- option [] $ do
                    string "else"
                    ws
                    manyTill forthExp (try $ lookAhead $ string "then")
    string "then"
    return $ If yes no

doLoop = do
    string "do"
    ws
    body <- manyTill forthExp (try $ lookAhead $ string "loop" <|> string "+loop")
    choice [string "loop" *> return (DoLoop body False), string "+loop" *> return (DoLoop body True)]



----------------

main :: IO ()
main = do
    s <- getContents
    execParse s
```

[Mirror](http://lpaste.net/94976)

Use execParse in GHCi to parse and run a program.

Example:

```
execParse ": neg (n -- n') 0 swap - ; 'enter a number to negate' CR in neg . 'looping' CR 0 50 do i . -5 +loop true if 'always print this' else 'never print this' then dump"
```

In this project I've tried to use Parsec, a small transformer stack and basic lens functionality. Comments on the use of these are what I'm after, but everything helps.

I've used `NoMonomorphismRestriction` to deal with Parsec. It can't infer types but the types are too complicated to figure out myself. I was wondering whether this could be because of type synonyms and whether there's an easy guide to typing Parsec functions, or maybe I'm complicating things too much.

I've found using transformers pretty straightforward, and it matches pretty well with lens. But, all lens operators have State versions except the getters, which makes it pretty awkward. I can use zoom, but that isn't always pretty (can't be used with `^?` for example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `popStack` might look a little nicer using the `LambdaCase` extension:

```
popStack :: ForthS Integer
popStack = use stack >>= \case
  []     -> throwError "Empty stack. Can't pop!"
  (n:ns) -> stack .= ns >> return n
```

The same transformation can occur with `popLoopStack`.  It also applies to `peekLoopStack`, but in that case, you might even use `maybe` rather than a language extension:

```
peekLoopStack :: Int -> ForthS Integer
peekLoopStack = maybe (throwError "Loop stack is empty.") return
              . zoom loopStack . gets . flip atMay
```

You could also use `maybe` to eliminate the `do` in `getWord`.

---

You have a lot of binary operators.  Each one is implemented like this:

```
eval (Plus) = do
  a <- popStack
  b <- popStack
  pushStack (b+a)
```

I think that’s a little repetitive.  I might define a little helper function:

```
binop :: (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> Eval
binop f = do
  a <- popStack
  b <- popStack
  pushStack (f b a)
```

Then you can define your operators like this:

```
eval Plus = binop (+)
eval Min  = binop (-)
eval Mul  = binop (*)
-- ...
```

This leaves less room for error.

---

In a similar vein to the first suggestion, you might try to eliminate the `do` from `Call`:

```
eval (Call key) = getWord key >>= mapM_ eval
```

---

`xor` is `/=`.  There is no need to define `xor` when you could just use `/=`.

---

### `forthExp`

`comments >>= pure . Cmt` can be replaced with `fmap Cmt comments` or `Cmt <$> comments`.  Similarly for `integer`, `stringLike`, and calls.

`char '-' *> pure Min` can be replaced with `Min <$ char '-'`.  Similarly for the others.

The outer structure, too, can probably be changed.  Rather than using

```
foldl1 (<||>) $ map (\e-> e <* (ws1 <|> eof))
```

I think this would be clearer:

```
choice $ map ((<* (es1 <|> eof)) . try)
```

---

I would avoid the name `ifThenElse`, as that is used by GHC’s `RebindableSyntax` extension should you ever want to use it in the future.

---

### Transformer stack

Your transformer stack looks okay, but I might consider replacing the underlying `IO` with a free monad providing only the operations (input, output) you need, and then provide an interpreter to use `IO`.  This makes it trivial to test, as you can make it pure by just inspecting the resulting structure rather than using the `IO` interpreter.  See [this blog post](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html) for more details.